# Synergy to share mouse only (not keyboard)

Tags: synergy

Synergy is very handy for single mouse/keyboard set sharing between multiple PCs. But I have a laptop (WinXP SP3) and a desktop (OS X Snow Leopard), a mouse, a keyboard which plugs to desktop. I don't need to share keyboard since each has one. Is there any way to share mouse only? Since if keyboard sharing enable might cause inconvenience. Thanks.

PS. Another quick question is how to stop synergy daemon on Mac OS? synergys --help doesn't give any information.

Comment: out of interest, in what kind of situation is such a set up useful? so you'd be  moving your mouse cursor to a different screen, then getting off your chair to another keyboard. and while you type at one screen, you're worried somebody else might type on the other keyboard and into your screen?  I remember 15 years ago, 386/486 days, those old computers had a keyboard lock, you put the key into the computer case, and turned it and no keyboard input was possible. Though you probably want a software thing to enable/disable keyb input depending on whether the cursor is on the screen.

Comment: for stopping synergy, if there's no exit option in the tray icon, how about killing the process, like one would kill any other. this seems to be how one can do it on the mac http://8help.osu.edu/1253.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would work, because when you move the mouse cursor off the server the active window is defocused, so if you could type on the server's keyboard there would be no active window for the keypresses to go in to.

Synergy does not disable the client keyboard, so when you have moved onto another PC you can still type on that PC's keyboard (as well as the server's.)

The only thing you cannot do is type on the server's keyboard and have it appear on the server, when the mouse is on another screen.

Answer (score 0):

(General site hint - please limit questions to only 1 question at a time)

Regarding killing synergy, bring up the terminal and type `sudo killall synergys`.  It will prompt you for your password.

I suspect it isn't possible to share the mouse and not the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Within your [config file](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Text-Config#options) you can use the keystroke() assignment with `none` to disable a key on the client. Usually it's used to disable a key that can cause problems on the client (such as altgr, or win or rctrl when certain apps are running), but it can be used to disable all keys, though you have to do it one key at a time.

```
 keystroke(key) = actions
```

It could be used in your situation like this:

```
 keystroke(AppMail) = none
 keystroke(AppMedia) = none
 keystroke(AppUser1) = none
 keystroke(AppUser2) = none
 keystroke(AudioDown) = none
 keystroke(AudioMute) = none
 keystroke(AudioNext) = none
 keystroke(AudioPlay) = none
 keystroke(AudioPrev) = none
 keystroke(AudioStop) = none
 keystroke(AudioUp) = none
 keystroke(BackSpace) = none
 keystroke(Begin) = none
 keystroke(Break) = none
 keystroke(Cancel) = none
 keystroke(CapsLock) = none
 keystroke(Clear) = none
 keystroke(Delete) = none
 keystroke(Down) = none
 keystroke(Eject) = none
 keystroke(End) = none
 keystroke(Escape) = none
 keystroke(Execute) = none
 keystroke(F1) = none
 keystroke(F2) = none
 keystroke(F3) = none
 keystroke(F4) = none
 keystroke(F5) = none
 keystroke(F6) = none
 keystroke(F7) = none
 keystroke(F8) = none
 keystroke(F9) = none
 keystroke(F10) = none
 keystroke(F11) = none
 keystroke(F12) = none
 keystroke(F13) = none
 keystroke(F14) = none
 keystroke(F15) = none
 keystroke(F16) = none
 keystroke(F17) = none
 keystroke(F18) = none
 keystroke(F19) = none
 keystroke(F20) = none
 keystroke(F21) = none
 keystroke(F22) = none
 keystroke(F23) = none
 keystroke(F24) = none
 keystroke(F25) = none
 keystroke(F26) = none
 keystroke(F27) = none
 keystroke(F28) = none
 keystroke(F29) = none
 keystroke(F30) = none
 keystroke(F31) = none
 keystroke(F32) = none
 keystroke(F33) = none
 keystroke(F34) = none
 keystroke(F35) = none
 keystroke(Find) = none
 keystroke(Help) = none
 keystroke(Home) = none
 keystroke(Insert) = none
 keystroke(KP_0) = none
 keystroke(KP_1) = none
 keystroke(KP_2) = none
 keystroke(KP_3) = none
 keystroke(KP_4) = none
 keystroke(KP_5) = none
 keystroke(KP_6) = none
 keystroke(KP_7) = none
 keystroke(KP_8) = none
 keystroke(KP_9) = none
 keystroke(KP_Add) = none
 keystroke(KP_Begin) = none
 keystroke(KP_Decimal) = none
 keystroke(KP_Delete) = none
 keystroke(KP_Divide) = none
 keystroke(KP_Down) = none
 keystroke(KP_End) = none
 keystroke(KP_Enter) = none
 keystroke(KP_Equal) = none
 keystroke(KP_F1) = none
 keystroke(KP_F2) = none
 keystroke(KP_F3) = none
 keystroke(KP_F4) = none
 keystroke(KP_Home) = none
 keystroke(KP_Insert) = none
 keystroke(KP_Left) = none
 keystroke(KP_Multiply) = none
 keystroke(KP_PageDown) = none
 keystroke(KP_PageUp) = none
 keystroke(KP_Right) = none
 keystroke(KP_Separator) = none
 keystroke(KP_Space) = none
 keystroke(KP_Subtract) = none
 keystroke(KP_Tab) = none
 keystroke(KP_Up) = none
 keystroke(Left) = none
 keystroke(LeftTab) = none
 keystroke(Linefeed) = none
 keystroke(Menu) = none
 keystroke(NumLock) = none
 keystroke(PageDown) = none
 keystroke(PageUp) = none
 keystroke(Pause) = none
 keystroke(Print) = none
 keystroke(Redo) = none
 keystroke(Return) = none
 keystroke(Right) = none
 keystroke(ScrollLock) = none
 keystroke(Select) = none
 keystroke(Sleep) = none
 keystroke(Space) = none
 keystroke(SysReq) = none
 keystroke(Tab) = none
 keystroke(Undo) = none
 keystroke(Up) = none
 keystroke(WWWBack) = none
 keystroke(WWWFavorites) = none
 keystroke(WWWForward) = none
 keystroke(WWWHome) = none
 keystroke(WWWRefresh) = none
 keystroke(WWWSearch) = none
 keystroke(WWWStop) = none
 keystroke(Space) = none
 keystroke(Exclaim) = none
 keystroke(DoubleQuote) = none
 keystroke(Number) = none
 keystroke(Dollar) = none
 keystroke(Percent) = none
 keystroke(Ampersand) = none
 keystroke(Apostrophe) = none
 keystroke(ParenthesisL) = none
 keystroke(ParenthesisR) = none
 keystroke(Asterisk) = none
 keystroke(Plus) = none
 keystroke(Comma) = none
 keystroke(Minus) = none
 keystroke(Period) = none
 keystroke(Slash) = none
 keystroke(Colon) = none
 keystroke(Semicolon) = none
 keystroke(Less) = none
 keystroke(Equal) = none
 keystroke(Greater) = none
 keystroke(Question) = none
 keystroke(At) = none
 keystroke(BracketL) = none
 keystroke(Backslash) = none
 keystroke(BracketR) = none
 keystroke(Circumflex) = none
 keystroke(Underscore) = none
 keystroke(Grave) = none
 keystroke(BraceL) = none
 keystroke(Bar) = none
 keystroke(BraceR) = none
 keystroke(Tilde) = none
```

You'd also need to make assignments for the letter and other keys, through the \uXXXX syntax:

```
 keystroke(\u0001) = none
 keystroke(\u0002) = none
 keystroke(\u0003) = none
```